# AngularJS smart-table strict search

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

Smart-table has a built in functionality to search through columns (st-search). Is it possible to perform a strict search for words, so with an exact match? For example: if I have table like this: id, name, status:

- 1, John, address somewhere
- 2, Johnny, another address
- 3, Jane, address

and do a search for 'John' only the first row should show. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. My solution was to use the undocumented stSetFilter feature to pass in my own custom filter.

```
<table st-set-filter="myFilter" st-table="myData">
```

Then you just create an angular filter.

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('myFilter',
  function($filter) {
    return function(input, predicate) {
      return $filter('filter')(input, predicate, true);
    };
  }
);
```

In my case I needed to only do strict searches some of the time so I put some additional logic in the filter, but this will do you for doing strict searches all the time.

Mine looks more like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('myFilter',
  function($filter) {
    return function(input, predicate) {
      var strict = false;
      if (predicate) { // some conditional if I want strict
        strict = true;
      }
      return $filter('filter')(input, predicate, strict);
    };
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Old, but still relevant.
If you have multiple input fields, but want strict only on some.
@elthrasher gave me the idea.

```
angular.module('app').filter('myStrictFilter', function($filter) {
    return function(input, predicate) {
        var response = input,
            strict = false,
            custom_predicate = {};
        // some input fields must be strict
        angular.forEach(predicate, function(value, key) {
            custom_predicate = {};
            custom_predicate[key] = value;
            strict = false;
            if (key === 'completion_status') { // strict it is.
                strict = true;
            }
            response = $filter('filter')(response, custom_predicate, strict);
        });
        return response;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo should use strict comparator:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" />
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{ name:query }:true">
      {{ user.id }}, {{ user.name }}, {{ user.address }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

> Comparator which is used in determining if the expected value (from
>   the filter expression) and actual value (from the object in the array)
>   should be considered a match.
>
> Can be one of:
>
> **function(actual, expected):** The function will be given the object
>   value and the predicate value to compare and should return true if
>   both values should be considered equal.
>
> **true:** A shorthand for function(actual, expected) { return
>   angular.equals(actual, expected)}. This is essentially strict
>   comparison of expected and actual.
>
> **false|undefined:** A short hand for a function which will look for a
>   substring match in case insensitive way.
>
> Primitive values are converted to strings. Objects are not compared
>   against primitives, unless they have a custom toString method (e.g.
>   Date objects).

Comment: Thanks! Although, I'd like to make use of smart-table's search function as I'm using its pipe plugin (http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#section-pipe). Any thoughts on that?